# IntelliJ not recognizing dependencies imported by Maven?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am not quite sure what has happened to my IntelliJ recently but any new projects created or checked out from a repo are unable to resolve the dependencies from maven.

Resulting in lots of unresolved class symbols.

Interestingly projects that have already existed work fine and IntelliJ can resolve the dependencies imported by Maven.

So something has happened within the space of the last two weeks that has caused this issue. I haven't touched the Intellij config

This is what I have done to troubleshoot:

- clear cache in intellij
- mvn clean and install
- reimport through maven on intellij
- download sources and documentation
- remove maven pom and re-add it
- checked m2/repository cache, which contains the libraries

IntelliJ version - **2018.2**

Any ideas?

Comment: Is IntelliJ pointing to use your installed version of maven or the internal bundled version?

Comment: Bundled version 3